# Detach a bash script launched by tomcat

Tags: bash

I have implemented a dashboard servlet for my linux server. I wanted to add an option for "restart main services" to this dashboard. Basically the dashboard just run bash script with the ProcessBuilder object from java.
My main services are just tomcat and postgresql. When I want to restart postgresql, I have to restart tomcat too because if I don't, the existing connection to the database are aborted and even if I restart postgresql, tomcat cannot access my database anymore.

So there is the simple script I use to stop services :

main_services_restart.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service tomcat stop
sudo service postgresql stop
sudo service postgresql start
sudo service tomcat start
```

If I run it manually, all is going well. But because I run it from my tomcat dashboard, when it calls the script, the script will stop the tomcat service so the script itself is stopped too and so tomcat isn't restarted.

I tried to create differents scripts to detach the main script like this :

```
sudo -b nohup /home/me/scripts/main_services_restart.sh
```

or even :

```
sudo /home/me/scripts/main_services_restart.sh & disown
```

But this isn't detaching the script from tomcat. How can I completely detach the script from the ProcessBuilder of tomcat ?

Comment: take a look at [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect). it can run your script in background as a daemon so stopping tomcat would not stop the script.

Comment: Have you ever used it ? I successfully made it but I am having some difficulties to use it. Can you provide me a simple bash script to achieve what I am trying to do ? I randomly tried something like "sudo ./sexpect -sock /tmp/sexpect-test.sock spawn /home/me/scripts/main_services_restart.sh" But it doesn't seem to work. I think I'm not getting the point of the -sock arg

Comment: try `sexpect -s /tmp/some.sock spawn -nowait sudo /home/me/scripts/main_services_restart.sh`. here's another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50285060/900078

Comment: The command you provided me works ! Thanks a lot !